# Calling a WCF service with wsHttpBinding in Android giving an exception when security mode message

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soap, android-ksoap2

**Calling a WCF service with wsHttpBinding in Android giving an error**

I'm using ksoap2 in android for communication with wcf service.

Following is error generated when I call WCF Service

*Code: s:Sender, Reason: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.*
Following is my android code.

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IMyServiceOne/MethodOneTest";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MethodOneTest";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL1 = "myUrl";//for privacy

//onCreate()

//Creating Soap Object
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

       Element e = new Element();
       e.setName("To");
       e.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
       e.addChild(Node.TEXT,URL1);


       Element e1 = new Element();
       e1.setName("Action");
       e1.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
       e1.addChild(Node.TEXT,"http://tempuri.org/WCFLast/ServiceOneTest.svc");

//Creating SoapSerializationEnvelope and seeting values to it

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope2.dotNet=true;
// add HederOut to envelope
envelope2.headerOut = new Element[] { e, e1 };
envelope2.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

//Creating HttpTransportSE object and making call to the service
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL1);    
     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope2);  
     final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope2.getResponse();
     final String str = response.toString();
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, 5000).show();
```

Comment: Why are you creating the soap-request manually and don't use any framework?

Comment: @khlr I have no idea about any framework for soap-request in android. Can you please tell me about any framework for soap-request in android.

Comment: Sorry, I'm Not very familiar with android develeopment. I just wondered why you built the requests "by hand". But you should find Tons of Info on that topic via a simple web search. Have a try with `JAX-WS` or something like that.